# Material Perception and Quantity

Tags: perception

It appears to me all our senses that allow us a perception of the world give us only a relative measure of quantity from the world‘s projection or reflection.

The world returns relative measure from a notion of difference from one thing and another. This measure of difference results in a quantity determined by the choice of scale we use.

The perception of space that our vision gives us returns a relative measure between one object and the next, allows us a Cartesian-based perception from these quantities, and gives us three dimensions and perspective.

Sound results from a pressure difference of quantity from the movement of the air that vibrates our physical body. Our minds interpret that vibration and give it sound.

Objects return visual information that has different quantities of frequency and our minds recognise this quantity difference and interpret it is as colour.

Touch we have returns information from the depression of the skin, but comes from a relative measure of quantity in the depression from another touch.

The whole of human perception comes from information from the world with its senses from a relative measure between it and another and that quantity from scale. I propose that without a mind to perceive the relative measure, there would be no colour, no sound, etc.

The mind gives quality to the experience of that quantity, and without that quality the world is completely abstract and meaningless. Those qualities give value to experience and the material world is void of quality and value unless there's a mind to give it colour.

I don't know where I'm going with this. I think I'm arguing that the nature of the object world and the subject that interprets the world are undoubtebly inextricably linked. They are either simultaneous or eternal in their manifestation, make that word “redundant”, in eternal because of its nature and the necessity of time in its definition. The object did not give the subject a need for its definition from that sequence the definition of each relies the existence of each other.

Comment: Please add your question. Which question shall be answered?

Comment: I don't see a question here, though the concept that the interpretations of the world from the perspective of a subject are entwined with the subject itself is a common philosophical approach.

Comment: @Cort Ammon thanks for your comment, a common philosophical approach that counter argues the scientific approach of a sequence of object then subject such as their 'theory' of the big bang and the evolutionary process this started which arises a subject from its process which results in the observation of it.